# Updating one record in large table using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table containing millions of records.
I want to update only one record using update sql query with where clause.
What should I do to execute this update query in minimum possible time. Suggest.

Comment: Regrettably the question is not as easy to answer as you might think. What's the RDBMS? What's the table structure? What's the filter column type? Do you have indexing?

Comment: it depends upon what rdbms is in question and also Please USE transaction for updationation and also please take into account indexes on columns applied

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the record using the primary key in the table:

```
update t
    set . . . 
    where <primary key> = ?;
```